# Help plotting polar functions

Tags: calculus

The problem is finding the common interior of $r = 4 \sin \theta$ and $r = 2$. I can plot the graphs of both of them from $0, 2\pi$, but having trouble when trying to plot the interior.

I know the graphs intercest at $\theta = \pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$

I know the answer is $8/3\pi-2\sqrt{3}$

I know that $r=2$ makes up the top section and $r=4\sin\theta$ is the bottom.

I tried $\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} (1/2)(2^2)d\theta - \int_{5\pi/6}^{13\pi/6} 1/2(4\sin\theta)^2 d\theta$ however, that doesn't give the correct answer .

Where exactly am I making my mistake?

Figured it out:

$f(\theta) = \begin{cases} 4\sin\theta & 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/6 \\ 
2 & \pi/6 <\theta 5\pi/6 \\ 4\sin\theta & 5\pi/6 < \theta leq \pi \end{cases}$

Then sum the  integrate 1/2\int_{lower}^{upper} (f(\theta))^2 d\theta$ for each interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we need to consider the way polar integration works:  What we need to use here, is that theta is rotating from $0$ to $\pi$:

- as $\theta$ rotates from $0$ to $\pi/6$, radius is measured by $r = 4\sin \theta$.
- as $\theta$ rotates from $\pi/6$ to $5\pi/6$, radius is measured by $r = 2$.
- as $\theta$ rotates from $5\pi/6$ to $\pi$, radius is measured by $4\sin \theta$.

And then we are done. this gives us:

$$\frac 12\int_0^{\pi/6} (4\sin\theta)^2\,d\theta + \frac 12\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}4\,d\theta +  = \frac 12\int_{5\pi/6}^\pi (4\sin\theta)^2\,d\theta$$

Comment: I liked your previous answer better, it seems more compact.

Comment: I have got the same message so I'll do the same.